# Why do I get an ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql' error?

Tags: python, mysql, ubuntu

I am currently trying to work out a Python Script but I keep on getting the same Exeption

This is my exact script I get the error on:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import mysql.connector
import os
import datetime
from mysql.connector import errorcode

os.system("./mysqldumpBashScript.sh")

def search_str(file_path, word): 
    f = open(file_path, 'r')
    filedata = f.read() 
    f.close()

    now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%w_%m_%Y_%H_%M")
    newdata = filedata.replace('classicmodels', 'classicmodels_' + now)
    
    f = open(file_path, 'w')
    f.write(newdata) 
    f.close()
    
    
search_str(r'latestDBBackup.sql', 'classicmodels')
```

I already checked if I have the mysql-connector module installed and I also tried to reinstall it but it hasn't helped yet.

Comment: And your error is ?

Comment: Are you running this in an IDE or at a command-line?  Exactly how did you install `mysql-connector`?  You're sure you installed it in Python 3 and not Python 2?  And if you're just post-processing a `mysqldump` output, why do you need `mysql.connector` at all?  If you're just renaming a table, you don't need `mysqldump`.

Comment: @TimRoberts I am running it in a command-line. I installed mysql-connector using the commandline (python3 -m pip install mysql-connector-python). I am pretty sure that I installed it on Python 3. I need it later on so that I can execute a SQL-Script but I didn't include the whole script.

Comment: If you do `which python3`, does it map to `/usr/bin/python3`, or do you have another one installed somewhere?

Comment: @TimRoberts it does map to /usr/bin/python3

Comment: Then I have no answer.  I've used this on dozens of systems and it has worked every time.

Comment: which editor ?  can you verify the version of python that the editor is using ?